# Is this the correct syntax for liquid mapping

Tags: azure, mapping, liquid

So I've simplified my liquid map but this is the part I'm having a problem with, can someone tell me the correct syntax for dividing the value of the input? I've tried the first line as it is, with only one curly bracket and also without curly brackets, none seem to work?

```
{% assign my_integer = {{content.vehicleSpecification.engine | divided_by: 100}} %}
{
    "engineSizeCC": {{ my_integer }}
}
```

Also if anyone knows of a liquid mapping tool online that they could let me know about it would be very appreciated, the old one I used is now a dead link (https://masterdatapoc.z6.web.core.windows.net/)

Thank you in advance,
Kyle

Answer (score 0):

You should do it without the curly braces:

```
{% assign my_integer = content.vehicleSpecification.engine | divided_by: 100 %}
{
    "engineSizeCC": {{ my_integer }}
}
```